# how to print \\ in C? (fprintf)

Tags: c, printf, backslash

The question how to print one \ is already asked for many times.
I couldn't find anything about printing two backslashes (`\\`).

When I try to write this:
`fputs("\\\\",w_ptr);`

there won't be more backslashes than one.

If you are interested:

it's a custom bill writing program which creates Latex PDF with a csv feed.
And there are a lot of double-backslashes in there which indicate a new line feed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for \\ try `fprintf("\\\\",w_ptr);`

Comment: What is `w_ptr`? And where is the first parameter to `fprintf` -- the file you want to print to? (Show us the code you are using to print one backslash and we can show you how to adjust it to print two.)

Comment: thank you ,too! It works now. :)

Comment: w_ptr is acutally a file pointer, it's just a name for better understanding this thing. ;) I use both fprintf and fputs, and I corrected it to fputs("\\\\",w_ptr); both cases are similar with escape sequences and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already know how to print one backslash, printing two of them should be easy.

```
fprintf(file, "%s\n", "\\"); // one backslash
fprintf(file, "%s\n", "\\\\"); // two of them
```

Oh, and **always activate compiler warnings**. The first argument to `fprintf` must be a file pointer, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

Sample program to print two backslashes in file sample.txt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen ("sample.txt", "w+");
    if ( !fp )
    {
        printf ("[ERROR]: Opening sample.txt");
    }
    fprintf (fp, "%s\n", "\\\\");
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```